# Mongo Container Not Retrieving Persisted Data

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers, volumes

I'm running a mongo container with the command below:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v /home/ayuba/Royal/RoyalRide/uploads:/data/db --name mongod mongo
```

This works fine and the data is persisted in the directory (/home/ayuba/Royal/RoyalRide/uploads) as seen on the image here: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVa4X.png"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVa4X.png%22)

However, whenever i restart my ubuntu server, and run the mongo container again using thesame volume, it does not retrieve any of the previous data from the volume.